Math Operators with Changing Sub-Properties?
Over on Stackoverflow somebody asked a question a long time ago about custom operators in Javascript.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/20728460/10981777
Their specific request was for an operator:
(ℝ, Ϡ), x Ϡ y = x + 2y
(∘ swapped to Ϡ (sampi) for lack of confusing similarity to dot product)
Working on a different idea (simple library of Javascript functions) I stumbled across a method I thought might work.
Number.prototype["Ϡ"] = function(y){ return this + 2 * y; };

var Ϡ = "Ϡ";
var result = (2)[Ϡ](2);
// console.log( result ) prints 6 like expected

Implemented as a page you can just copy into a text file to test (JS doesn't seem to work on this forum)
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Static Info and Links-->
        <title>Quick demo of math operators</title>
        
        <!-- Variable -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function main(){
            Number.prototype["Ϡ"] = function(y){ return this + 2 * y; };

            var Ϡ = "Ϡ";
            var result = (2)[Ϡ](2);
            
            var out_string = "Formula is: 2 Ϡ 2<br>";
            out_string += "Where: (R,Ϡ), x Ϡ y = x + 2y<br>";
            out_string += ("Result is: " + result);
            document.getElementById( "output" ).innerHTML = out_string;
            console.log( result );
            // Formula is: 2 Ϡ 2
            // Where: (R,Ϡ), x Ϡ y = x + 2y
            // expands out to result = 2 + 2 * 2;
          }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="main()" onmousedown="" onmouseup="" onmousemove="">
      <div id="output">Initial Text That Should Be Replaced</div>
    </body>
</html>

However, this then led to another idea, because of Javascript and objects having properties, the operator might have changing sub-properties.
Extending above:
Number.prototype["Ϡ"] = function(y){ return this + (this["Ϡ"].incr++) * y; };
Number.prototype["Ϡ"].incr = 2;

var result = [(2)[Ϡ](2),
              (2)[Ϡ](2),
              (2)[Ϡ](2),
              (2)[Ϡ](2),
              (2)[Ϡ](2)];
// console.log( result ) now prints out [6,8,10,12,14]

Actual Question: Is there a term for this in math?  The closest I found was cases like "perform operation (if result was returned from first filter)".  It kind of looks like a Fibonacci Sequence if the + operator were changing.
However, I haven't been able to find anything where the operator itself changes with each application of the operator.  Possible I may not recognize the notation or name.
"Morphological Operator" from https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/morphological-operator or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology) sounds kind of similar, yet I can barely figure out what they're writing.  They talk about increasing operators, yet they seem mostly interested in "points in a neighborhood" not "historical point history".

I've never seen anything like this in mathematics (and I think it would be extremely confusing). I think it would be better expressed as some kind of recursive definition, and/or as a function with an additional argument that represents how many times it has been applied so far.

Ok, not heavily invested in the idea or anything.  Like noted below with Deusovi answer, just curious if it already had a math name.  Call them Gabriel Putnam Operators or something, that nobody in math likes and believe would be horribly confusing.

This isn't a thing in mathematics.
In math, we use side-effect-free operations. To properly reason about things, any statements about them need to remain true; if we declare that $2\mathrel{Ϡ}2 = 6$, then we had better be able to say "$(2\mathrel{Ϡ}2) + 1 = 7$"! Facts about an entity (in thise case, the $Ϡ$ operation) should not change based on how many times we mention it!
Instead, we'd model this as a bunch of different operators: $Ϡ_1, Ϡ_2, Ϡ_3, \ldots$, defined as:
$$x\mathrel{Ϡ_n}y \quad=\quad x+(n+1)y$$
This lets us make statements without having to worry that the very act of making such a statement is changing the value out from under us.
We'd do the same with basic variables too, of course: the stateful line of code x *= 2; would be 'translated' into the stateless, eternally true  "$x_t = 2x_{t-1}$".

In general, 'stateful' operations aren't needed in math. As functional programmers can tell you, higher-order operations make variable reassignment pretty much obsolete: if we have the map and reduce functions, we don't actually need to write for(int i=0;i<n;i++){do stuff;} anymore.
And many loops are really just 'for all' statements, only expressed as iterative processes because those computer scientists keep insisting on things like "time is linear!" and "the computer has to actually perform operations in a sequence, it can't just will eternal truths into existence!".
If we really needed to do something extremely stateful, with no good way of doing otherwise, we'd probably just express it as pseudocode.

Ok.  That answers my question.  Mostly curious if it had a name already I could include like "blah blah blah operator" or "long dead human's operator" or something.  Kind of seemed like something the math community did not use, and your answer makes that rationale fairly clear.

Box checked.  This seems like plausible aggregate math community response.  Like above just call them Gabriel Putnam Operators or something that nobody uses.
